# NaCl - Rebus puzzle

Tags: rebus

Solve the following rebus puzzle:

```
  NaCl * H2O
  H2O * NaCl
 ------------
   CCCCCCC
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Answer**

> Sailing (Saline), Sailing over the seven seas (Cs)

Comment: How'd you get "saline"?

Comment: @CoolGuy Saline is a solution of salt (NaCL) in water (H2O).

Comment: @KSmarts thanks for explaining that to Cool Guy